# Access APP_CONFIG['var'] inside routes? or supply routes with variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, routes

I need to do in rails 4 supply some ip address to set a constraint on certain routes.
Is there a way to get this data from a config file without harcoding it into the routes file?

Im using a yaml file and initializer for app variables like:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/application.yml")[Rails.env]
```

so normally I could do:

```
  constraints(:ip => %w[APP_CONFIG['app_url']]) do
    .. my routes..
  end
```

This fails in the routes.rb is there a way to fix this?

Comment: what happens when you inspect `APP_CONFIG` in the routes file?

Answer (score 1):

The `routes.rb` file is a ruby file which is instantiated once, and loaded into memory.

You can just add the ruby code inside it and it will be executed once:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  app_config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/application.yml")[Rails.env]
  constraints(:ip => %w[app_config['app_url']]) do
    .. my routes..
  end 
end
```

This will instantiate the routes.rb file with the variable loaded from the yml and available throughout your rails routes app. You don't even need to use a env variable. Local variable seems a better idea.

You can also put logic inside and make it environment dependant:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  app_config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/application.yml")[Rails.env]
  constraints(:ip => %w[app_config['app_url']]) do
    .. my routes..
  end
else
   .. my routes ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the initialization process of rails (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html). You'll see that routing is actually loaded quite early (and earlier than application.rb or other initializers). It has therefore not yet loaded this file.

A way round this would be to place this into your boot.rb:

```
# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exist?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
#Now load app config:
require 'yaml'
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../../config/application.yml', __FILE__))
```

Comment: Would this have side effects? Your solution seems correct but im afraid it has side terms, will grand it as the correct answer though.

Comment: This would need a require 'yaml' also and then still fails on the Rails.root, because  `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

Comment: Then adding require 'rails' throws more errors like WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset: so this seems kinda unresolvable. Perhaps I should allow the routes but just authenticate inside the controller level. Although cutting out the routes would have been better. Anyone an idea?

Comment: can do this without needing rails, see edit. Not sure about the RAILS_ENV though. Although this may work rather than Rails.env as its an envinroment variable

Comment: Actually, when routig is loaded, you don't have access to the rails env so not sure you can do this on a per-env level

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running into a load order issue. You could probably hack around this, but...

I would highly recommend using Figaro to solve this problem. It is a gem specifically designed for rails configuration and will work nicely with 12 factor app deployments (like Heroku): https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

I am using Figaro in the app I am currently working on and was able to confirm access to the env variables within my routes file. I believe this gem will solve your current issue and other config issues you don't even know you have yet!